# Reload Django dev server when certain files changes

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to tell the Django development server to listen to changes on some files (not the regular Python files in the project, they already creates a reload) and reload if these files have changed?

**Why do I want this?** When my gulp-script builds the JS and CSS, it takes all files and appends a hash to them. My working file *frontend/css/abc.css* will be built to *build/css/abc-hash123.css*. This so that browsers are forced to reload the content if anything has changed since last deploy. When this builds, a manifest file is created that contains the mappings. In the settings in Django, I read this manifest file at start and get all these mappings ([from this example here)](https://thusoy.com/blag/9). If I change a file, it gets a new hash, and a new manifest is written. The mappings currently loaded into the memory are then wrong, and thus I need to force a reload of the development server to get the new mappings.

*Clarification*: I got comments on using a VCS. So just for clarification: I use a VCS and check in my *abc.css*. *abc-hash123.css* is automatically built as a part of the build system.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you should consider using git or a VCS of your choice to track version changes instead of creating your own version control with file names.

Comment: is there any particular reason you use versioned-by-name-change css files? In general I would consider this an anti-pattern, as versioning is something best left to a VCS and not part of the filenames. If you are concerned about web server caches that don't get refreshed unless the name changes, consider adding something like `?_v=<versionid>` to the css links. this will cause the caches to miss. same effect, less hassle.

Comment: @Atsch I don't use this to track version changes. The file I work on that is checked in to vcs always has the same name. It is just the built version, to force web browsers to download the new css or js file when something has changed.

Comment: @miraculixx I used that before. But what I've read, this doesn't work as one wants to in all browsers and with bots. Also, I think it is more hassle, as I need to update the file manually when a new version is released. With a hash of the content, I get around this and everything is automated.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson browsers won't serve content from cache if there is a different url query attached to it (the part that's after the `?` in the url). If you encounter such a browser, don't use it, it's useless as you never know what you get.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson  _I need to update the file manually when a new version is released_ - I'd recommend to rethink your build process, this kind of thing should be fully automated. if not you're likely to pull your hair time and again...

Comment: @miraculixx: Maybe the browsers handle this nowadays. But you also have crawl-bots and proxies. Renaming the file, as far as I know, will work in all cases.

Comment: @miraculixx: Yes. That is what I've been doing, and that is why this problem came up :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) goes this is not supported.

This is a bit hacky, but just `touch`ing (or changing the timestamp in any other way) some `.py` file or some other file that development server observes (e.g. `settings.py`) in your build will do the job.

Also as comments suggest, versioning is better left to a VCS.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would work as an absolute last resort. But that would always give me modified files when checking in my work.

As for the comments about versioning and VCS, I might have been a bit unclear in my question; I only check in the *abc.css*. The renaming and appending of a hash is a part of the build stage, to force browsers to download the new file if content has changed.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson I don't see how exactly it's a last resort if you are doing the same thing in your solution =)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky way, but I found a way to make force the Django server to reload on changes to the *build* directory. After some research on the Django autoreload module, I found that it only listen to changes on Python files, from modules that are loaded into *sys.modules*. So, I only needed to make the build directory a Python module:

In my build script (gulp), after I've built my files, I added a step to create the *__init__.py* file, to make the build directory a module. Then I also wrote a comment in this file that contains a time stamp, making it unique for each build:

```
fs.writeFile('./build/__init__.py', '#' + Date.now())
```

And then in my *local.py* (the settings to use locally), I simply import this new module, so it appears in *sys.modules*:

```
try:
    import build
except ImportError:
    print("Could not import from build folder. Will not auto reload when building new files.")
```